# IO which is executed out of order

Tags: haskell

I created simple program. Take some input and repeat it but...IO is executed out of order. What can I do with it?

```
main = putStr "Plese write some characters: " >>
       getLine >>= (\str -> putStrLn $ "You wrote "++str++"!") >>
       putStrLn "Bye"
```

Comment: What do you mean by out of order?  What order is it executing in right now?  Have you also tried setting the buffering mode via `System.IO.hSetBuffering`?